# How to make ion-element float on ion-header

Tags: javascript, css, ionic4

I want to make the icon goes between the header and content section

but its keep going UNDER the header section..

This is the result I get:

[image]

my html code

```
<ion-header >
<ion-toolbar class="header">
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-title class="app-title" text-center>My app</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>

<ion-toolbar class="header">
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col text-center routerLink="/mails-to-sign">
          <p class="stat-title">Courriers à signer</p>
        </ion-col>
        <div class="verticalLine"></div>          
        <ion-col text-center routerLink="/action"> 
            <p class="stat-title"> Actions à réaliser </p>
        </ion-col>
        <div class="verticalLine"></div>
        <ion-col  text-center routerLink="/refused-mails"></p>
            <p class="stat-title">Courriers transmit</p>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>

</ion-toolbar>
```

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-icon class="add-mail-btn" color="success" name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
</ion-content>
```

My css

```
.add-mail-btn{
 font-size: 60px;
 position: absolute;
 top: -5%;
 left: 79%;    
}
```

Comment: Can you produce a demo of the code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for the **[ion-fab](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/fab)** component:

[image]

```
<ion-content>
 <!-- 
      fab placed to the top and end and on the top edge 
      of the content overlapping header 
 -->
  <ion-fab vertical="top" horizontal="end" edge slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button>
      <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>

...

</ion-content>
```

Please notice that the position of the button is achieved by using the following **[properties](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/fab#properties)**: `vertical="top" horizontal="end" edge`

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for